# Cruising To & From The U.K

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules, cruising

I want to go on a Norwegian Fiord cruise leaving from and returning to the U.K.  Are the days at sea and when going ashore counted towards your 90 days in a Schengen zone?